# Cassandra rpc_timeout

Tags: cassandra

I'm using Cassandra 1.2.11. I created the following column family:

```
CREATE TABLE subscribers_all (
subscriber text,
status int,
package text,
SW_ON timestamp,
S_NUMBER text,
USER_NAME text,
updated_date timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY (subscriber)
);
```

I created a Java application to delete all entries with an updated_date older than a given timestamp. I used the following select statement in a while loop:

```
select * from subscribers_all where token(subscriber) > token(?) limit 100;
```

I started the program. It was working well. Then I realized I'd given a wrong timestamp, so I killed the program. I hadn't attached any shutdown hooks, so the cluster wasn't shutdown properly.
I started the program again, with the correct timestamp. The Cassandra Driver was throwing the following error (I tried several times):

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)

So, I decided to test the select in cqlsh. Even the following simple select isn't working:

```
select subscriber from subscribers_all limit 1;
```

It always throws this error:

> Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.

When I put a where clause in my select, it works fine.

```
select * from subscribers_all where subscriber = 'xyz';
```

I get the expected result.
I tried restarting the entire cassandra cluster. It's of no help.

In the log file, I can only see one Exception, which I think corresponds to the time when I killed my application:

> ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests:973721] 2013-12-12 15:08:29,699 ErrorMessage.java (line 210) Unexpected exception during request
>   java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

No other exception for my cqlsh selects or for the times I tried restarting my application. 
'nodetool tpstats' shows that I have no messages dropped, nor blocked or pending.

Someone was suggesting that it might be 'due to time sync between the nodes'. I verified and the servers are synced.

I enabled tracing and I executed again both the select that works and the one that doesn't. 
Here is what the trace shows for the ok select (hopefully I'm allowed to paste url's).

http://pastebin.com/7D6gYRms

Here is a fraction of what the trace shows for the query with 'LIMIT 1':

http://pastebin.com/50ksph3k

I'm almost sure that it's a bug, but is there any solution to it? 
I refuse to drop the column family and recreate it :) 
It's not a feasible solution when going live.

Comment: What does tracing show on the query that works `select * from subscribers_all where subscriber = 'xyz';`

Answer (score 3):

Check your GC inspector, when you are querying the Cassandra if the garbage collection process is going on for long time Cassandra wont allow you to perform any other operations until the garbage collection process is over, and hence you may get this exception.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read
query at consistency ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded).
```

If this is the problem you have to tune the garbage collection process . Go through [this](http://blog.mikiobraun.de/2010/08/cassandra-gc-tuning.html)

To visualize the GC operations and generational sweeps and memory graphs, open up the JVisualVM tool tha's supplied with JDK and install VisualGC plugin with that. Check [this](http://visualvm.java.net/images/visualgc.jpg) out.

Comment: Unfortunately, we stopped using Cassandra after this issue, so I can't verify if this was the reason. However, I do not believe this was the case, because if it was a problem with the GC I would have expected to have the same result (the timeout) for all my queries. Instead, this only happened when I didn't put the WHERE clause. Hopefully, other people who ran into this issue will comment further, since I don't have Cassandra installed anymore.

Comment: I had the same problem and I found it was related to having Solr enabled on my table. It turned out I was trying to use `WHERE` clause on non-indexed field and for some reason I didn't get informed about that. I have found traces to that in Solr logs. After creating the missed index, the problem disappeared.

Comment: There is usefull info here https://support.datastax.com/entries/69902949-ReadTimeoutException-seen-when-using-the-java-driver-caused-by-excessive-tombstones when the errors happens due to many tombstones (deletes). The suggestion is to decrease gc_grace_seconds for the table.